# How to add Custom Ports in LoadBalancer on Azure VM's with OpenShift setup/ARO setup

Tags: azure, openshift, azure-load-balancer, aro

I want to add some custom ports in LoadBalancer on my Azure-OpenShift setup(It might be ARO cluster/Azure VM's with OpenShift installer).

- Do we have option to edit/configure Azure loadbalancer for changing custom ports?
- If yes, Which is the best way to do. For Example, editing in service manifest or yaml with my custom ports or from AZURE UI etc.
- Scenario: I have a customer, where I can say please do these steps for changing ports in loadbalancer and you can have your own Ports which has to present for his Azure-OpenShift setup.

Comment: Why does the customer need to change ports on Load balancer? Please write more details of background of requirements.

Comment: As part of my investigation & documenting it. I have a scenario that if a customer has already having some knid of firewall where they have custom port to use/restrict for his deployment. 

One more point is our clusters are deploying in Red Hat OpenShift. If we use Azure Env like Azure VM's with OpenShift setup (or) ARO clusters for deploying our product with custom Ports which we want to add either from AZURE UI/configuring LoadBalancer manifests/ Configurable readimate Yaml's for service/etc., (Like this any options do we have from Azure Env?)

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift cluster has loadbalancers for API and Ingress.
OpenShift 4.x doesn't manager the API loadbalancer so you can change configuration of the loadbalancer from Azure portal. However, on ARO, you can not change the load balancer on Azure portal because all the resources managed by Azure *1.

For the ingress loadbalancer, that is managed by Load Balancer Service. So, you should modify a yaml file on you cluster as cluster administrator. However, the service is deployed by Ingress Operator. If you removed/changed the service content, Operator may roll back your service as it is.
I couldn't find any option on the documentation *2. But you can try to modify the service as you want.

*1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/openshift/openshift-service-definitions#azure-resource-architecture

*2: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.11/rest_api/operator_apis/ingresscontroller-operator-openshift-io-v1.html